# Is there a way to edit the Nautilus "Other Application" menu

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, menu

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

When using Nautilus and right-click on a file I get a drop-down menu, the first two items are “Open With *Default application*” and “Open With Other Application”.

I use Mirage as my default application for most image files.

On one computer. when I right-click on an image file and choose “Open With Other Application”, Mirage is the preselected application not “Image Viewer” which is my usual second choice.

On my other Ubuntu 18.04 computers, Mirage isn’t listed as it’s the default application.

Is there a way to clean up this menu so when I don't want to use Mirage, it isn't on the "Other Application" list?

Thanks

Based on some now-deleted suggestions:

I used the "Properties"->"Open With" to select “Image Viewer” and set it as the default. But that didn't work, it went back to Mirage as the default. I tried setting other programs as the default the same way and none stuck, it always returned to Mirage.

I went to Settings->Details->Default Applications and changed the “Photos” from Mirage to “Image Viewer”. That worked and when right-clicking and selecting “Other Application” Mirage is preselected.

But when I changed Settings->Details->Default Applications->“Photos” back to Mirage the problem returned. Mirage is the default and the preselected “Other Application”.

---

March 18, 2020 I submitted this as a bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1867943

Comment: It normally does but in this case it always selects Mirage no matter what other application I chose.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on an image file and select : 'Open With Other Application'
Then right click on the application that you do not want to be on that menu.
Click on 'Forget assocation'

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about this feature.

I was able to get two other applications to be forgotten but not Mirage.